# Insert CLOB from a function to table in PLSQL 11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, clob

I have a table

```
    CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."FILES" 
   (    "FILE_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TEXT" BLOB, 
    "FILE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "HTML_CONTENT" CLOB, 
     CONSTRAINT "FILES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("FILE_ID"));
```

I want to insert HTML Format in HTML_CONTENT column. I've written the function that is returning the html content of files:

```
    create or replace function get_html(
v_file_id in scott.files.file_id%type) return clob
 as

l_clob clob;
v_file_name scott.files.file_name%type;
v_bfile bfile;

begin
select file_name into v_file_name from scott.files where file_id=v_file_id;
v_bfile := bfilename( 'FILES', v_file_name );
ctx_doc.policy_filter( 'my_policy', v_bfile, l_clob, false );
      return l_clob ;

end;
```

The thing I want is to insert this content in HTML_CONTENT column. I am using the procedure for insertion of files and it's relevant content. All insertion is going well except the HTML content. It's inserting null values in clob column

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE 
(
  DIR_NAME IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'FILES'
, FILE_NAME IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
 l_clob clob;
l_blob blob;
l_bfile bfile;
html_format clob;  
f_id pls_integer;

BEGIN

f_id:=S1.nextval;

--html_format:=get_html(S1.currval);
 insert into scott.files (file_id,file_name, text,html_content)
    values (f_id,FILE_NAME, empty_blob(),empty_clob())
    returning text,get_html(f_id) into l_blob,html_format;

--insert into scott.files(html_content) values (html_format);

  l_bfile := bfilename( DIR_NAME, FILE_NAME );
  dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile );
  dbms_lob.loadfromfile
    (l_blob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ) );
  --  html_format:=get_html(S1.currval);
    dbms_output.put_line(html_format);
     dbms_lob.loadfromfile
    (html_format, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ) );
  dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );
  commit;


END LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE;
```

Please help me to create the mechanism is such way that when a new document insert it should be able to generate and insert that html content in that clob column.

Comment: Your insert is using `empty_clob()`, so you'll have that rather than null. (And `text` will be empty too). You're returning the empty BLOB to `l_blob`, and then looking up the file via the function which goes into `html_format` - but that never goes into your table. The rest of the procedure seems to be duplicating the function, but also not doing anything with the results. What are you expecting that to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert is setting `text` to and `html_content` to empty LOBs (not null). You're returning those but don't do anything with them (`l_blob` is replaced by the later `load-from_file()` call; and `html_format` is printed but then also replaced).

I think you can simplify this quite a bit; if you're going to read the file in the procedure anyway then you don't need the function, and don't need to read it multiple times:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE 
(
  DIR_NAME IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'FILES'
, FILE_NAME IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 

  l_bfile bfile;
  l_clob clob;
  l_blob blob;

BEGIN

  l_bfile := bfilename( DIR_NAME, FILE_NAME );

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_blob, false);

  dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile );
  dbms_lob.loadfromfile
    (l_blob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ) );
  dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );

  ctx_doc.policy_filter( 'my_policy', l_blob, l_clob, false );

  insert into files (file_id, file_name, text, html_content)
  values (s1.nextval, FILE_NAME, l_blob, l_clob);

END LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE;
/
```

Untested as I don't have CTX packages available, or your policy, but seems to do what you intended... it [compiles](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b728bdb17af97e0fce4e10bc73e9e48) though, at least.

Comment: Don't edit your question; you could have put that error as your comment on my answer.

Comment: @SumaiyaQureshi - I'd missed the `dbms_lob.createtemporary` step - added now (and tested, up to successful file load anyway).

Answer (score 0):

***Thanks for rapid response Alex. Trying the following strategy but getting error* ORA-22290: operation would exceed the maximum number of opened files or LOBs
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 805
ORA-06512: at "SYS.LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 3
22290. 00000 -  "operation would exceed the maximum number of opened files or LOBs"
*Cause:    The number of open files or LOBs has reached the maximum limit.
*Action:   Close some of the opened files or LOBs and retry the operation.**

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE 
    (
      DIR_NAME IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'FILES'
    , FILE_NAME IN VARCHAR2 
    ) AS 

      l_bfile bfile;
      l_clob clob;
      l_blob blob;

    BEGIN

      l_bfile := bfilename( DIR_NAME, FILE_NAME );
      dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile );
      dbms_lob.loadfromfile
        (l_blob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ) );


      ctx_doc.policy_filter( 'my_policy', l_blob, l_clob, false );

      insert into scott.files (file_id, file_name, text, html_content)
      values (s1.nextval, FILE_NAME, empty_blob(), empty_clob()) returning text,html_content into l_blob,l_clob;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_clob);
    dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );
    END LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Successfully inserted by this logic**

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE 
    (
      DIR_NAME IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'FILES'
    , FILE_NAME IN VARCHAR2 
    ) AS 

      l_bfile bfile;
      l_clob clob;
      l_blob blob;

    BEGIN
    insert into scott.files (file_id, file_name, text, html_content)
      values (s1.nextval, FILE_NAME, empty_blob(), empty_clob()) returning text,html_content into l_blob,l_clob;
      l_bfile := bfilename( DIR_NAME, FILE_NAME );
      dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile );
      dbms_lob.loadfromfile
        (l_blob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ) );


      ctx_doc.policy_filter( 'my_policy', l_bfile, l_clob, false );


     -- dbms_output.put_line(l_clob);
    dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );
    END LOAD_FILE_TO_TABLE;
```